# Copy and paste formatting is slow using VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

The following code is a function that works. It's just slow and I don't know how to speed it up. It takes an Excel row number and the value of its headerval (string) and finds the same headerval on a different sheet then copies the formatting and applies it to our new sheet. The true false is because the source sheet has 2 different formatting options. It passes in the row to use either 23 or 24. ZROW is a public variable which is set with the ROW to start looking. srccolbyname function gets a col number from the source sheet which has the same headerval.

```
Function formatrow(roww As Long, header As Boolean)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim headerval As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEALSHEET")
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
If header = True Then: srcrow = 23: Else: srcrow = 24
LastColumn = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 2 To LastColumn
headerval = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, x).Value
srccol = srccolbyname(headerval)
sht2.Cells(srcrow, srccol).Copy 'THIS IS SLOW
sht.Cells(roww, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats,    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Function
```

As requested here is the support function referenced above.

```
Public Function srccolbyname(strng_name As String) As Integer
Call findcol 'find ZROW
Dim x As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(22, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 2 To LastColumn
        chkval = sht.Cells(22, x).Value
            If Trim(UCase(chkval)) = Trim(UCase(strng_name)) Then
            srccolbyname = x
            Exit For
        Else
        srccolbyname = 2
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

Comment: What's `srccolbyname` doing?

Comment: added it per your request. It's just finding the col number for the matching col

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
If header = True Then: srcrow = 23: Else: srcrow = 24
```

Would be much better off as an `IIf` statement:

```
srcrow = IIf(header, 23, 24)
```

Also note, this:

```
If {boolean-expression} = True Then
```

..is always redundant and can be written as:

```
If {boolean-expression} Then
```

With `header` being a `Boolean` already, there's no need to compare it to a Boolean literal to obtain a `{boolean-expression}`!

---

One of the most important things to do when you have *blocks* in your code (`If...End If`, `For...Next`, `While...Wend`, `Do...Loop`, but also `Sub...End Sub`, etc.), is *indentation*.

Here's your function, properly indented:

> ```
> Function formatrow(roww As Long, header As Boolean)
>
>     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>     Dim headerval As String
>     Dim sht As Worksheet
>     Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEALSHEET")
>     Dim sht2 As Worksheet
>     Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
>     srcrow = IIf(header, 23, 24)
>     LastColumn = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
>
>     For x = 2 To LastColumn
>         headerval = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, x).Value
>         srccol = srccolbyname(headerval)
>         sht2.Cells(srcrow, srccol).Copy 'THIS IS SLOW
>         sht.Cells(roww, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
>                                         SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
>         Application.CutCopyMode = False
>     Next x
>
>     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
> End Function
> ```

Notice how much easier it is to see where the loop starts, where it ends, and what's in its body.

Now sure what `ZROW` is, it's not declared in the scope of `formatrow` so I'm assuming it's a module-scoped constant and that other procedures in that module as using it. If only `formatrow` uses it, it should be scoped to `formatrow`.

You declared `sht` and `sht2` as `Worksheet` objects; you should be querying the `Worksheets` collection, not `Sheets` (which contains charts and other sheet types).

But then, if these sheets aren't dynamically generated, you shouldn't need to query any worksheet collection and get the objects by their "sheet name" (which the users can change at any time!) - instead, use their "code name": VBA defines a global-scope object for every Excel object (including `ThisWorkbook`, but also `Sheet1` and every sheet in the workbook), so you can use the *Properties* toolwindow (<kbd>F4</kbd>) to set their `(Name)` property to a meaningful identifier, and then use that identifier in code, so you can delete all these:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEALSHEET")
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

And then do this (assuming the sheet labelled "DEALSHEET" is named `DealSheet`):

```
LastColumn = DealSheet.Cells(ZROW + 1, DealSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

And this:

```
headerval = DealSheet.Cells(ZROW + 1, x).Value
```

And that:

```
Sheet1.Cells(srcrow, srccol).Copy 'THIS IS SLOW
```

And so on.

---

Now, about performance. You need a radically different approach. How would you do it if you were going to do it manually? Would you Copy+Paste one cell at a time, or Copy+Paste the whole row at once?

You want to copy/paste the formats on `srcrow` from column 2 through `LastColumn`: *do that*.

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(srcrow, 2), Sheet1.Cells(srcrow, LastColumn)).Copy
DealSheet.Range(DealSheet.Cells(roww, 2), DealSheet.Cells(roww, LastColumn)) _
         .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                       Operation:=xlNone, _
                       SkipBlanks:=False, _
                       Transpose:=False
```

No need to loop, no need to lookup column numbers. Unless I missed something. Should be much faster!

---

I also ran [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases) inspections (build 2.0.10, not released yet). A few things to note:

- `formatrow` is implicitly public. Consider specifying an explicit access modifier.
- `sht`, `sht2`, `strng_name` and `x` are poor names. Consider renaming them; avoid disemvoweling, numeric suffixes, underscores, type prefixes, and 1-2 character identifiers.
- `formatrow` is a `Function`, but its return value is never even assigned so it always returns an implicit `Variant/Empty`; it should probably be a `Sub`.
- Parameters `roww`, `header`, and `strng_name` are implicitly passed by reference, and can safely be passed by value (`ByVal`) instead.
- Explicit `Call` syntax is obsolete. Use the implicit call syntax instead (which you've used to call `srccolbyname` anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate the detailed answer.  The reason I was checking cell by cell is because the source page might not have the same cols and order of cols as the destination page. We need the ability for the user to add cols without breaking the VBA.

Comment: Hmm this does change things. I've added a number of Rubberduck inspection results.